# iOS Development: problematic framework search path

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-simulator

I have an iOS app and I want to test it on simulator. When I run the project xcode complains that my framework file is **"missing required architecture i386 in file".**

I did a bit of search on line and it says that's because xcode used the framework files intended for actual device when building the project for simulator. Solution is to add the simulator framework folder under the framework search path in build settings.

Okay now the problem is, doing that solves the problem of building project on simulator, but later when I want to build the project on an actual device, xcode starts complaining again saying **there are redefinitions of some of the openGL typedef in the framework.** To fix this I have to remove the search path item that I added.

So is there an easy way to avoid having this kind of problem? I don't want to switch the search path over and over again when I want to build the project on different platform.

Comment: Is this an iOS 4 SDK project that you've upgraded to 5.0 or is it a project you originally worked on in XCode 3 and recently upgraded to 4?

Comment: @Inturbidus Hah, yes I originally worked on the project with Xcode 4.2, and now it wouldn't work on another Xcode 4.3.2. Freakin evil xcode!

Comment: I thought that might be it.  I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade a project from 4.2 to 4.3.2 style it often loses the architectures required for the target you are building for.  Usually you just have to add them back or change the target SDK.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do you add them back?

Comment: If you want to support older architectures (iPhone 3GS, etc) you'll go to build settings and add armv6 under architectures.  If you don't care about older support you can change your target SDK to the latest.  You can also check mark "build for current architecture only" for testing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll figure that out... hopefully.